# parameterised query to prevent SQL injection

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, sql-injection

can someone please help me re-write this line of code to parameterise the variable CMA_AAP_ID before it's passed to the GetList method?

```
public virtual IList<KGV_CMS_PHYSICAL_MAPPINGS> GetAssociatedPhysicalMappings()
{
    return CMS_MAPPINGS.GetList(string.Format("from CMS_MAPPINGS as MAPPINGS where MAPPINGS.MAP_ID in ( select MAP_ID from FIELD_MAP_APP as FieldsAppls where FMA_APP_ID = {0} )", CMA_APP_ID));
}
```

Comment: No, because strings can’t be parametrized and we don’t know what `GetList` does or how it could be modified

Comment: static public IList<KGV_CMS_PHYSICAL_MAPPINGS> GetList(string query)
        {
            using (NHibernate.ISession session = NHibernate.NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession())
            {
                return GetList(session, query);
            }
        }


static internal IList<KGV_CMS_PHYSICAL_MAPPINGS> GetList(NHibernate.ISession session, string query)
        {
            return session.CreateQuery(query).List<KGV_CMS_PHYSICAL_MAPPINGS>();
        }

Comment: Please do not paste code into comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```
string sqlQuery = "from CMS_MAPPINGS as MAPPINGS where MAPPINGS.MAP_ID in ( select MAP_ID from FIELD_MAP_APP as FieldsAppls where FMA_APP_ID = @id";
```

then try the following:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(/* some connection info */))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
  var idParameter = new SqlParameter("id", SqlDbType.int); // change here
  idParameter.Value = 10;

  command.Parameters.Add(idParameter);
  var results = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: command.Parameters.Add("id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 10;